# CURL request to API with custom Authentication Token returning "error 401"

Tags: php, api, curl, request-headers

So, i have an API created in Laravel that is expecting a **Header** named "*API-Token*" with the token as it's value in order to allow access to the user.

I'm trying to do **curl** requests to it in order to be able to include live examples in my documentation. Currently i'm using:

`curl -i  --header "API-Token: XXXXXXXXXXXXX" http://example.com/api/blahblah`

It's not working and i don't really know what else to do, i tried doing `-H` as well, and several other types of commands I've seen online such as

```
curl -i -H "Authorization: API-Token XXXXXXXXXXXX" -H "Accept: application/json" http://example.com/api/blahblah
```

The result is always a 401, what am i doing wrong? How can i get this request to work with curl?

Comment: Authorization is not a custom header but a standard header,
are you tryed this: curl -i -H "API-Token:XXXXXXXXXXXX" -H "Accept: application/json" http://example.com/api/blahblah

Comment: Yes, i just got it to work now, i must have typed something wrong, but sadly it appears my documentation (apiDoc) doesn't support it as it keeps giving me 401's even when the same curl request works perfectly on the cmd

Comment: Go through this ,see if it helps http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html